# What does the translator value tilda mean Symfony - fosUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Trying out the fosUserBundle module. Nowhere in the documentation I can see the meaning of the tilda ~ while configuring fosUserBundle in Symfony.

## app/config/config.yml

```
             framework:
                translator: ~
```

Comment: It's mean "default value" in symfony config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tidle means `null` in Yaml (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format#nulls).

In Symfony, setting an option that can be enabled to `null` or `true` means: Enable it with the default options. This means:

```yaml
framework:
    translator: ~
    # or
    # translator: true

# is a shortcut for
framework:
    translator:
        enabled: true
```

In this particular case, the full `framework.translation` config is:

```yaml
framework:
    translator:
        enabled:   false
        fallbacks: [en]
        logging:   "%kernel.debug%"
        paths:     []
```

So `framework.translator: ~` in this case means enabling translation features of Symfony using `en` as fallback locale, the `%kernel.debug%` parameter to indicate if logging should be enabled and no paths configured.